# Unable to pass a bash variable as a python argument in bash

Tags: shell-script, python, amazon-s3

For some reason I cannot pass the bash variable `$FOLDER` as a python argument on the following code. The python script downloads some files from amazon s3.

Bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=$(./aws get $BUCKET"/location.txt")
python /data/pythonscript.py $FOLDER
#
```

The output of the `$FOLDER` is a regenerated date eg. `2014/07/31/14-16-34` which is used as a path.

Here is the python script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto, sys
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

access_key = 'accesskey'
secret_key = 'secretkey'
bucket_name = 'a name'
folder_path =  str(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else ''

print("Forwarded folder path " + folder_path)

conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)

print("Bucket Location:" + bucket.get_location())

for key in bucket.list(prefix=folder_path, delimiter=''):
        if '.' in key.name:
                file_name = key.name[len(folder_path)+1:]
                print("Downloading file " + file_name)
                key.get_contents_to_filename('/data/temp/' + file_name)
```

When I execute the bash script without changing the `python /data/pythonscript.py $FOLDER` line, I get the following output:

```
Forwarded folder path 2014/07/31/14-16-34 
Buckect Location:
```

But when I change it to `python /data/pythonscript.py 2014/07/31/14-16-34` , everything works:

```
Forwarded folder path 2014/07/31/14-16-34
Bucket Location: 
Downloading 2014/07/31/14-16-34/FacetedSearch.zip 
Downloading file FacetedSearch.zip
Downloading 2014/07/31/14-16-34/Location.zip
Downloading file Location.zip
Downloading 2014/07/31/14-16-34/LocationPage.zip
Downloading file LocationPage.zip
```

Comment: What about this doesn't work?  Does the python script not get called with `$FOLDER` expanded?

Comment: Python is getting the $FOLDER argument but rest of the code doesn't work as expected. But if I change the  /data/pythonscript.py $FOLDER
to /data/pythonscript.py 2014/07/31/14-16-34 in bash script, it works. Python file also works from command line independently.

Comment: You've framed your question nicer than a lot of new users, but "rest of the code doesn't work as expected" is still pretty vague. What happens? Is there an error? What is the value of `folder_path` when using the bash variable `$FOLDER` as the argument?

Comment: Man, is `s3download.py` the same script, you called `pythonscript.py` earlier?

Comment: Just a minor complaint, but you mistyped bucket: `Buckect Location` in line 16.

Comment: Yes Bob the script is called 'pythonscript.py' and not `s3download.py` , sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the `aws` bash command is returning non-printable characters that you don't see with `print()`. Try removing them with `tr`:

```
FOLDER=$(./aws get $BUCKET"/location.txt" | tr -cd "[:print:]")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to put `$FOLDER` inside double quotes:

```
python script.py "$FOLDER"
```

Change the first line of your script to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This should work.

And be more clear on your questions.

As [@drs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147669/unable-to-pass-a-bash-variable-as-a-python-argument-in-bash#comment-239343) said, your question is still incomplete:

- Your examples are still vague and with flaws, like what is the correct name of your script, is it `pythonscript` or `s3download`?
- Is it "work as expected" supposed to have a blank value for
  `bucket.get_location()`?

Comment: I tried your suggestions but unfortunately, I am still getting the same result. The script is named `pythonscript.py` and the `bucket.get_location()` indeed returns a blank value. But apart from that blank value the script manages to download the files from amazon s3 when I use the mentioned method.